# SFCertificatePanel in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, ssl-certificate

Is anyone familiar with using SFCertificatePanel class ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/securityinterface/sfcertificatepanel?language=objc)) in Swift? Or is there another way to present a panel with X.509 certificate information ...

I. Nikolov